# In React When I am doing get call why data is not coming automatically, If I refresh the page then only data is coming?

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a React project, In my project I have three components Home, Signup, List.
There is nothing in Home component, In Signup component I have a Registration form, In List component I am getting data from the Backend. Now I put the List component in Signup component,
Now If I register in Signup component, I have to see the registered user details in the same page
But the data are not updating dynamically. For updates data If I refresh the page, then only data are updating. Someone please help me how to overcome this issue.

Api is working fine.

If you feel I am not clear with my doubt, please put a comment.

Thanks in advance

This is Signup.js

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import './Signup.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import List from '../List/List';

function Signup() {

    const [data, sendData] = useState({})

    const postData = async () => {
        try {
            const result = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/signup', data)
            sendData(result)
            console.log(result)
        } catch {

        }
    }

    const handleChange = ({ target }) => {
        const { name, value } = target
        const newData = Object.assign({}, data, { [name]: value })
        sendData(newData)
    }

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log(data)
        postData()
    }

    const myForm = useRef(null)
    const resetForm = () => {

        myForm.current.reset();

        }

    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col-12'>
                    <div className='col-4'>
                        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} ref={myForm}>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="firstname">Firstname</label>
                                <input type="text" name='firstname' onChange={handleChange} className="form-control" id="firstname"></input>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="lastname">Lastname</label>
                                <input type="text" name='lastname' onChange={handleChange} className="form-control" id="lastname"></input>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                                <input type="email" name='email' onChange={handleChange} className="form-control" id="email"></input>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                                <input type="password" name='password' onChange={handleChange} className="form-control" id="password"></input>
                            </div>
                            <button onClick={resetForm} type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className='col-12'>
                    <List></List>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Signup
```

This is List.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './List.css';
import axios from 'axios';

function List() {
    const [data, iterateData] = useState([])

    const getData = async() => {
        try {
            const result = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/signup')
            iterateData(result.data)
            console.log(result.data)
        } catch(error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getData()
    }, [])

    return(
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col-12'>
                    <table className='table table-bordered'>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Firstname</th>
                                <th>Lastname</th>
                                <th>Email</th>
                                <th>Password</th>
                                <th>Delete</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {data.map(currentValue => 
                            <tr>
                                <td>{currentValue.firstname}</td>
                                <td>{currentValue.lastname}</td>
                                <td>{currentValue.email}</td>
                                <td>{currentValue.password}</td>
                                <td><button className='btn btn-danger'>Delete</button></td>
                            </tr>
                            )}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default List
```

Comment: List fetches the data when it mounts and then never refreshes. State changes in Signup never propagate down to List.

Comment: How are requesting the List updates? timer? button? As @rayhatfield mentioned, current setup will only update on mount.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change useEffect method.

Try this: Signup.js

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import './Signup.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import List from '../List/List';

function Signup() {

    const [data, sendData] = useState({})
    const [registered, setRegistered] = useState(false)

    const postData = async () => {
        try {
            const result = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/signup', data)
            sendData(result)
            setRegistered(true)
            console.log(result)
        } catch {

        }
    }

    const handleChange = ({ target }) => {
        const { name, value } = target
        const newData = Object.assign({}, data, { [name]: value })
        sendData(newData)
    }

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log(data)
        postData()
    }

    const myForm = useRef(null)
    const resetForm = () => {

        myForm.current.reset();

        }

    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col-12'>
                    <div className='col-4'>
                        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} ref={myForm}>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="firstname">Firstname</label>
                                <input type="text" name='firstname' onChange={handleChange} className="form-control" id="firstname"></input>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="lastname">Lastname</label>
                                <input type="text" name='lastname' onChange={handleChange} className="form-control" id="lastname"></input>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                                <input type="email" name='email' onChange={handleChange} className="form-control" id="email"></input>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                                <input type="password" name='password' onChange={handleChange} className="form-control" id="password"></input>
                            </div>
                            <button onClick={resetForm} type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className='col-12'>
                    <List registered={registered}></List>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Signup
```

List.js

```
function List(props) {
    const registered = props.registered
    const [data, iterateData] = useState([])

    const getData = async() => {
        try {
            const result = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/signup')
            iterateData(result.data)
            console.log(result.data)
        } catch(error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getData()
    }, [registered])

    return(
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col-12'>
                    <table className='table table-bordered'>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Firstname</th>
                                <th>Lastname</th>
                                <th>Email</th>
                                <th>Password</th>
                                <th>Delete</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {data.map(currentValue => 
                            <tr>
                                <td>{currentValue.firstname}</td>
                                <td>{currentValue.lastname}</td>
                                <td>{currentValue.email}</td>
                                <td>{currentValue.password}</td>
                                <td><button className='btn btn-danger'>Delete</button></td>
                            </tr>
                            )}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default List
```

Comment: Hi @Khayankhyarvaa Turmandakh by applying your code also, I have to refresh page to change data.

Comment: Please debug your code. like this: function List(props) { console.log(props) ...
if log is different. We can find another solution in List.js. Else We should change SignUp.js

Answer (score 0):

if you call get api of users in Signup page only this will solve your problem. and for every user create you don't have to call the list api again and again
Signup.js

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import List from "./List";

function Signup() {
  const [data, sendData] = useState({});
  const [data1, iterateData] = useState([]);

  const getData = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/signup");
      iterateData(result.data);
      console.log(result.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  const postData = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api/signup", data);
      iterateData([...data1, result]);
    } catch {}
  };

  const handleChange = ({ target }) => {
    const { name, value } = target;
    const newData = Object.assign({}, data, { [name]: value });
    sendData(newData);
  };

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(data);
    postData();
  };

  const myForm = useRef(null);
  const resetForm = () => {
    myForm.current.reset();
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-12">
          <div className="col-4">
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} ref={myForm}>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="firstname">Firstname</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  name="firstname"
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  className="form-control"
                  id="firstname"
                />
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="lastname">Lastname</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  name="lastname"
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  className="form-control"
                  id="lastname"
                />
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                <input
                  type="email"
                  name="email"
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  className="form-control"
                  id="email"
                />
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                <input
                  type="password"
                  name="password"
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  className="form-control"
                  id="password"
                />
              </div>
              <button
                onClick={resetForm}
                type="submit"
                className="btn btn-primary"
              >
                Submit
              </button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="col-12">
          <List data={data1} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Signup;
```

List.js

```
import React from "react";

function List({ data }) {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-12">
          <table className="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Firstname</th>
                <th>Lastname</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Password</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {data.map(currentValue => (
                <tr>
                  <td>{currentValue.firstname}</td>
                  <td>{currentValue.lastname}</td>
                  <td>{currentValue.email}</td>
                  <td>{currentValue.password}</td>
                  <td>
                    <button className="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default List;
```

Comment: Hi @Vipin Yadav I tried your code but its not working.

Comment: it is saying your looping map of undefined

Comment: console log your data1

Comment: I tried your code but even though I have to refresh the page to get data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209690/discussion-between-cruse-and-vipin-yadav).

Answer (score 0):

it didn't render dynamically maybe because your Signup.js doesn't re-render after you submit. Try add `sent:false` initially in your state and then change it to `true` when you have submitted

Comment: I only have to rerender the List Component When I click submit button in Signup component. I think like this I have to write logic but I don't know how to write like that.

Comment: If you want re-render List component,  your List component's parent (Signup) has to re-render first in this case.

Answer (score 0):

`<List>` component populates only when it mount or unmount as you've defined in the `List` component

```
useEffect(() => {
    getData()
}, [])
```

So you should remount the `<List>` component when the data is available.

In React, if the `key` prop changed, react will remount the component.

Update the `data` state definition as below

```
const [data, sendData] = useState({ ok: false })
```

Update the `<List>` component use as below

```
<List key={data.ok.toString()}></List>
```

I use `data.ok` attribute which I assume you'll get in the response from `/api/signup`

So if you use as above, `data.ok` is `"false"` at initial load and once the registration api success `data.ok` will have `"true"` depending on the response you received.

This is just a solution to your problem. You should layout a better architecture.